# Fast way to pass data from C to Java via JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I use some fast communication library in c, but the rest of my application is written in Java. So I want to pass the received data to my java application.

As a Test I receive a message every 5ms for 1000 times.
This leads to that when the sender application has finished to send. the receiver application still needs time to process the data.

If I remove the line

```
(*g_env)->CallVoidMethod(g_env, store_callback, methodHandleMessage, top,
    ts, fo, msg);
```

The receiver application finishes immediately after the sender has sent the last message.

Is there any opportunity to speed that up?

```
void onMessageReceived(char* topic, char* timestamp, char* format,
    char* message) {
JNIEnv * g_env;
int getEnvStat = (*g_vm)->GetEnv(g_vm, (void **) &g_env,
JNI_VERSION_1_8);
if (getEnvStat == JNI_EDETACHED) {
    if ((*g_vm)->AttachCurrentThread(g_vm, (void **) &g_env, NULL) != 0) {
        puts("Failed to attach");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}

if (methodHandleMessage) {
} else {
    jclass clazz = (*g_env)->GetObjectClass(g_env, store_callback);
    methodHandleMessage =
            (*g_env)->GetMethodID(g_env, clazz, "handleMessage",
                    "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");

}
jstring top = (*g_env)->NewStringUTF(g_env, topic);
jstring ts = (*g_env)->NewStringUTF(g_env, timestamp);
jstring fo = (*g_env)->NewStringUTF(g_env, format);
jstring msg = (*g_env)->NewStringUTF(g_env, message);

 //This line takes too long!
(*g_env)->CallVoidMethod(g_env, store_callback, methodHandleMessage, top,
        ts, fo, msg);

}
```

Comment: You could Buffer messages on Java side and have them handled asynchronously ... then the call would only last as long as it takes to store the message in a queue.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the java method is empty at the moment

Comment: Well, you are still calling into the VM. That's not for free. How fast do you expect this to be?

Comment: It's hard if I get 10messages every 5ms and the method invocation takes ~1ms. Are there faster alternatives to pass data from C to Java? Would threading in C solve my problem? How could I do that?

Comment: Hmm ... MessageQueues, DataBases ... but if they are faster ... cannot possibly tell. Speed of JNI always was sufficient for my needs ... You are on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to shave a bit of time off of the `handleMessage` invocation by marking the class as `final`, which will eliminate the need to perform a virtual lookup.

If that isn't sufficient, and if `handleMessage` doesn't need to be called asynchronously, you could avoid calling it directly and instead store the arguments in a local C array that you will create and manage. And then you can notify the Java object that there is some data available by locking on it with `MonitorEnter`, invoking `GetMethodID(g_env, clazz, "notify", "()V")`, and then unlocking with `MonitorExit`.

Then on the Java side of things, the `store_callback` instance will have a dedicated thread that just waits for notifications, like so:

```
while (true) {
    synchronized (self) {
        wait();
        // we were informed that we received new data: now pull it out and process
        String[][] args = getBufferedArgumentsViaJNI();
        for (String[] arg : args) {
            handleMessage(arg[0], arg[1], arg[2], arg[3]);
        }
    }
}
```

Back on the native side of things, you will need to implement `getBufferedArgumentsViaJNI` to return and clear a JNI array of all the buffered arguments (left as an exercise to the reader).

As an astute reader, you may be wondering why this would be any faster, since you still need to invoke a JNI method in `onMessageReceived` as well as perform JNI synchronization, and so it will still be incurring JNI overhead. The answer is that while I can't guarantee that the message processing will be faster overall, the "wait" call is likely to be significantly faster since `wait()` is implemented as a native method on every JVM I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

The java method might be empty, but you still call GetEnv() each time, and you create 4 strings that you copy to Java. How large are those strings? I'd try to just call this method with some 10-20 characters strings and measure it. Another simple solution (if the method call is really slow) to call it with an array instead of string, and maybe even pack several strings into one array. Or you can also go with shared buffer (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#GetDirectBufferAddress)